# Get a comma seperated list from Inner join in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

```
  GroupMaster  [with columns Id Name]
  MemberMaster [with columns Id Name]
  MemberGroupMap [with columns Id GroupId [foreign key to group master] MemberId [foreign key to Member master] ]
```

I want to get the list of members with  their group names and i write this query and gets the result like this

```
SELECT mm.Id, mm.Name,gm.Name as GroupName 
from S4C6SMembermaster mm   
    inner join S4C6SMemberGroupMap mgm on mgm.MemberId =  mm.Id 
    inner join S4C6SGroupMaster gm  on gm.Id= mgm.GroupId

    4   dd  s1
    5   sknln   non teac staff
    6   hhk g2
    5   sknln   g2
    5   sknln   g1
```

How to get the GroupNames as a comma seperated list like below without repetition

```
    4   dd  s1
    6   hhk g2
    5   sknln   non teac staff,g2,g1
```

Comment: Hint: `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: How is this related to C# ?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0):

Link to definition of group_concat https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Comment: Please add the essential part from the link to make this a valid answer.